# Why is the one picture I uploaded under one profile, showing up under other profiles?

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-property, userprofiles

I'm new to SharePoint in my organization, so I would really appreciate any advice, even if it's just how to troubleshoot this more.

When I go in through Central Administration > User profile service > Manage User profiles > search a profile (let's say testuser1) and upload a profile picture for them, it is showing up in other user profiles.  Not all of them just a few random ones.  I was uploading a set of 11 different user profile pictures and it was changing the picture to the most recently uploaded for each one.  I thought it was contained just within the profiles I was touching, but I later realized it had also changed the photo for the person who was showing up in the Staff birthdays section on our staff portal page.  The results for this come from a javascript.

I only noticed this for the one person though.  When I tried uploading a picture today (on one of the profile from the original set), it changed it for yesterday's birthday person, but not for today's birthday person.

I had found a sort of related article that mentioned having <10kb for the photo size.  That has never been an issue for us before, but I tried it anyway.  Using a 2KB photos has the same results.

Like I said, I would appreciate any advice in troubleshooting this, since I'm not really familiar with all of the SharePoint components involved.  It's a really weird thing and I have yet to find any posts with a similar issue.  Thank you.